# Some class names are not getting highlighted, but they exist. How can I fix this?

Tags: c#, resharper, visual-studio-2013

I was just using VS + R# one day, and this happens:

[image: Why?]

To be clear, what I mean is the lack of syntax highlighting in the class name. It detects it, so why doesn't it highlight it? (The reason the first one is dimmed for no use is because I was just using it for some extra space, the solution is confidential and there's another MessageRecievedEventArgs somewhere in there). Why does this happen, and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Try removing and adding the references again. Another thing: restart VS and then rebuild your solution.

Comment: This happens to me randomly when I use ReSharper or CodeRush; usually due to a flaw somewhere else in the project (usually completely unrelated) or a missing explicit namespace reference.

Comment: @Steiner Any idea how to fix it? They're both in the same namespace btw.

Comment: @It'sNotALie. - Sadly I got it to work by just slapping around the VS IDE; I have to presume you're using VS2012; and it has the ability to change the source highlighting color very well; versus having to load configuration files from 3rd party site like previous version of Visual Studio.  Right click your solution/projects and see if there is a context menu item for "rescan" or "scan" project.  That's what did it for me; but I'm pretty sure CodeRush added that... R# might have something similar.

Comment: Aargh. I tried reinstalling, and now it's all class names. Sometimes I just want to go "f*** you, MS".